# Getting props.navigation undefined in React-native

Tags: react-native

In my main app page:

```
const App = StackNavigator({ sign-up: { screen: Signup }, });
```

on Signup page:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

<Text onPress={() => navigate(‘sign-up’)} Sign Up</Text>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should not use `-` in name or variables, it can be signUp

Comment: Thanks @JigarShah , I'm beginner at react-native :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it like mentioned in [this](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/832#issuecomment-297044355) github issue comment:

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen }, 
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```